# Unexpected variable behaviour

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3

long story short, when I do this:

```
 setup(props) {
       console.log(props.orders[0].order_line[0].reserved);
       let myOrders = props.orders.map((el) => el);
       myOrders[0].order_line[0].reserved = false; 
       console.log(props.orders[0].order_line[0].reserved,myOrders[0].order_line[0].reserved)
 }
```

I got this:

```
true
false false
```

Maybe I'm missing something basic but I even tried with the spread operator or Object.assign and still got the same result! Does someone knows what it can be?

Comment: Well, what result did you expect? You've got two arrays with the same objects in it, not copies.

Comment: Well I haven't tried the JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(o)) method but it seems to do the trick... Thank you.
Therefore, I still don't understand why .map, spread operator or Object.assign don't do the job as I always used them before in plain javascript with no trouble at all.

Comment: They don't do deep clones and never did. `I always used them before in plain javascript with no trouble at all.` Then you never needed a deep clone before.